# React-Native: Pass data to redux action to fetch API result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a component from where I am calling an action to fetch results from API, based on a data:

On press of this component:

Calling the fetchProducts() function on componentWillMount.

This below function is called:

```
fetchProducts(){
   this.props.fetchProductsHomeFromAPI({city:'ABCD'});
}
```

the mapDispatchToProps is something like this:

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({selectLocation: selectLocation, fetchProductsHomeFromAPI: fetchProductsHomeFromAPI}, dispatch);
}
```

The actions is as:

```
var FETCHING_PRODUCTS="FETCHING_PRODUCTS";
var FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = "FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS";
var FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAILURE = "FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAILURE";
var API = "https://api.abcd.in/get-home-products";

export function fetchProductsHomeFromAPI(data) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getProducts())
        fetch(`${API}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        city: data.city
                    })
                })
        .then(res =>res.json())
        .then(json =>dispatch(getProductsSuccess(json.results)))
        .catch(err => dispatch(getProductsFailure()))
    }
}

function getProducts() {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_PRODUCTS,
    }
}

function getProductsSuccess(data) {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

function getProductsFailure(  ) {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
    }
}
```

The combine reducer is :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import LocationReducer from './reducer-location';
import ActiveLocationReducer from './reducer-active-location';
import productsHome from './reducer-products-home';

export default combineReducers({
    location: LocationReducer,
    activeLocation: ActiveLocationReducer,
    productsHome : productsHome,
})
```

In index.android.js store is like this:

```
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import combineReducers from './src/Redux/reducers/combineReducers';

const store = compose(autoRehydrate())(createStore)(combineReducers)
persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, () => {
  console.log(store);
})


export default class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this error is **Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

Please help me to know this error. **Can't I pass data to my actions ?**

**Another question is , can I use another action's data in this action ?**

Comment: Not sure if it is related but You should change this `<Text onPress={this.fetchProducts()}>Press</Text>
` to `<Text onPress={this.fetchProducts}>Press</Text>` You are calling the function instead of passing the function as a prop

Comment: please check the updated code.

Comment: I am able to call the function properly. My issue is to pass data to API call in action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here What we can do is

```
import * as loginAction from '../../actions/login';

fetchProducts(){
var city = 'ABCD';
this.props.fetchProductsHomeFromAPI(city);
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
fetchProductsHomeFromAPI: (city) =>  dispatch(loginAction.sendToken(city),
});
```

This the action file where i have defined the action as you can(actions/login)

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
function checkdispatch(data) {
return createAction(constant.OPEN_USER_DRAWER)(data);
}

**value will be there in the sendToken function **
export function sendToken(city) {
console.log(city)
**here will call you API**
  dispatch(checkdispatch(true));
}
```

Hope this will help you with getting value to you action

Comment: Thanks ashutosh. It will be very helpful if you can please provide an example. As I am new to react-native and redux, its bit difficult to understand.

Comment: ok , will provide you , in couple of hour , if its not urgent

Comment: thanks a lot . Its urgent but , your effort worth it.

Comment: https://github.com/avtarvikas/dookApp/blob/develop/src/containers/DashboardContainer.js
with that code in bottom you can find out how we are calling some action

Comment: can you please tell, what is that dependency 'redux-actions' ?

Comment: if possible please give some easy example.

Comment: need to do npm to download the dependency
just used to create action , so that we can update the reducer